# Every nonzero homomorphism of a field to a ring is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I've read the following theorem:

> [image]

And am trying to understand what was done there. I think it is the following: We want to prove that

$$\text{Non zero hom of field to ring} \implies \text{hom is injective}$$

I think they used the contrapositive:

$$\overbrace{\varphi(a)=0 \;\wedge \;a\neq0}^{\text{hom not injective}}\implies \overbrace{\varphi(b)=0}^{\text{zero hom}}$$

Is that correct? I believe it is, I just want to confirm.

Comment: Yes, they used the contrapositive.

Comment: Yes. Every field homomorphism is either an injective map or the map that sends everything to zero. But, that is because it is a FIELD homomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you've understood it correctly. It is perhaps clearer to see it in the following way, though. Given a ring map $\varphi:k\to A$ from a field $k$ to a ring $A$, we know that $\ker \varphi$ is an ideal of $k$. The ideals in a field are $(0)$ or $(1)$. So, $\varphi$ is either injective when $\ker \varphi=(0)$ or the zero map when $\ker\varphi=(1)=k$.

Answer (score 2):

What is not said, but should have already been proven, if the homomorphism is not injective, it has a non-trivial kernel.

I would call this a proof by contraction.

Suppose we have a homomorphism with a non-trivial kernel.  Let $a$ be a non-zero member of that non-trival kernel.  Since the domain is field, then $a$ has an inverse.  Then by the algebra shown above, everything in the field must map to zero.

Comment: Yeah, that was proved before.